# Are both comma and colon redundant for JSON parser?

Tags: json, parsing

JSON I mentioned below is valid JSON.

I finished writing a parser of JSON which allowing only two basic data types of String and Object. Let me show what parser does in case of any ambiguity.

```
parse("{ "Mon": "weekday", "Tue": "weekday", "Sun": "weekend" }").get("Sun");//return value: "weekend"
parse("{ "weekday" : { "Mon": "1", "Tue": "2"} }").get("weekday").get("Mon");//return value: "1"
```

Function `parse` returns a dictionary from which we can get what we want.

I found that I didn't use any commas or colons to parse JSON, then I guess those notations may be also redundant for a full-data-type-supported JSON parser, is that true? If it is, they are for readability, right?

PS: what if it's invalid JSON? Same answer?

Comment: Yes you are indeed correct, full JSON has some stuff that isn't strictly necessary, for instance see here: http://www.relaxedjson.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 8259 (The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), the *colon* and *comma* are listed as **name-separator** and **value-separator** respectively.

See under section [2. JSON Grammar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2):

```
These are the six structural characters:

      begin-array     = ws %x5B ws  ; [ left square bracket

      begin-object    = ws %x7B ws  ; { left curly bracket

      end-array       = ws %x5D ws  ; ] right square bracket

      end-object      = ws %x7D ws  ; } right curly bracket

      name-separator  = ws %x3A ws  ; : colon

      value-separator = ws %x2C ws  ; , comma
```

So, they are both valid JSON separators with specific uses.

---

Refer section [9. Parsers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-9):

```
   A JSON parser transforms a JSON text into another representation.  A
   JSON parser MUST accept all texts that conform to the JSON grammar.
   A JSON parser MAY accept non-JSON forms or extensions.

   An implementation may set limits on the size of texts that it
   accepts.  An implementation may set limits on the maximum depth of
   nesting.  An implementation may set limits on the range and precision
   of numbers.  An implementation may set limits on the length and
   character contents of strings.
```

From the Parsers section, one can gather that there's no mention of skipping (ignoring) colon and/or comma because then the parser in question would not be conforming to JSON grammar.

---

Summing up, from the above sections, it is safe to say that any such decision of ignoring the JSON grammar would certainly be completely subjective implying that such parser is not conforming to the grammar.

So, that answers the question that the colon or comma are not redundant and they are essential part of the JSON grammar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: "Redundancy" means "isn't needed" not "isn't required"' the standard has nothing to do with this.  In fact a lot of JSON is redundant; you can find a simpler notation ("LIsp S-expressions") which in essence does everything JSON does with only (  )  and strings-of-nonblank characters.

Comment: What if the parser expects only valid JSON text?

Comment: @IraBaxter: Thanks for your input! Along that lines, I've added in my answer that it would be a "subjective decision of the parser writer" should he/she choose to ignore the standard grammar -- partially or completely.

Comment: @BINGZHAO: In that case, I believe the parser should be fully conforming to the standard JSON grammar to avoid any surprises i.e. corner cases. But, if there's some particular subset of JSON that you believe you can restrict somehow, you may choose to follow your own grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Json is a subset of JavaScript syntax. It's very small subset,  and so not all of the punctuation is necessary. But it is necessary in full expression syntax, because in many cases you cannot know where one expression in a list ends and the next one starts, unless there is a comma between them.

(There are alternatives to commas, of course. Lisp S-expressions don't need commas, as Ira Baxter points out, but they use more parentheses, which many people find noisier than commas.)

So as long as you consider it important to be able to insert JSON into a JavaScript text, you need to keep the JavaScript form, commas and colons and all.

One important aspect of JSON is that correct JSON is *safe*. You cannot insert untested JSON into an executable string, of course. That would be insane. But a JSON parser should validate its input, and validated JSON is safe to the ninect into code. If your parser lets you leave out the commas, that would no longer be rhe case.